# how to integrate chase payment gateway in php?

Tags: php, payment-gateway

The response what i get when i post values is `20400Invalid Request1`.
As per the documentation
http://www.ballwin.mo.us/images/file/3%20Certifcation%20FAQ.pdf

**13. Why am I receiving “20400 Invalid Request” error?**
This is an Apache server error meaning ‘page cannot be displayed’. This usually
indicates that Gateway services are unavailable. Once you are in production
contact Gateway Support

I donot understant what the error stands for

```
<?php
$url = "https://orbitalvar2.paymentech.net"; // testing
//$url = "https://orbital1.paymentech.net"; // production
$post_string="
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<Request>
<MarkForCapture>
<OrbitalConnectionUsername>*****</OrbitalConnectionUsername>
<OrbitalConnectionPassword>*****</OrbitalConnectionPassword>
<OrderID>123456782</OrderID>
<Amount>100</Amount>
<BIN>000002</BIN>
<MerchantID>**********</MerchantID>
<TerminalID>001</TerminalID>
<TxRefNum>4F320B79F23280DAE62777C80721F838FF13548D</TxRefNum>
</MarkForCapture>
</Request>";
$header= "POST /authorize/ HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header.= "Content-type: application/PTI53\r\n";
$header.= "Content-length: " .strlen($post_string) . "\r\n";
$header.= "Content-transfer-encoding: text\r\n";
$header.= "Request-number: 1\r\n";
$header.= "Document-type: Request\r\n";
$header.= "Interface-Version: Test 1.4\r\n";
$header.= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n";
$header.= $post_string;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
print curl_error($ch);
} else {
curl_close($ch);
}
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser,XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING,0);
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser,XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE,1);
xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $data, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
print ($data);
?>
```

Plesase help me out . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to edit your credentials out of that code.

Comment: i have already done that. thank you

Comment: <OrbitalConnectionUsername>*****</OrbitalConnectionUsername>
<OrbitalConnectionPassword>*****</OrbitalConnectionPassword>

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting this error because you are using an incorrect encoding header.

Change this line:

```
$header.= "Content-transfer-encoding: text\r\n";
```

To:

```
$header.= "Content-transfer-encoding: 8BIT\r\n";
```

That may fix your problem.

If not, also try explicitly casting your XML as UTF-8, using utf8_encode() on $post_string.

Comment: Try removing the encoding line altogether and utf-8 encoding your XML. If that doesn't work, I am out of ideas, except that I'm about 85% sure the problem is that the encoding specified by the header is not the encoding contained in the body of the request.